# In Servicenow i want to create a ui page which end users enters a value , it should be autopopulated to a field value after submission

Tags: servicenow

I am unable to pass the data from dialog window to server side on the case form

I was able to create a ui page and call it by client script . I was unable to pass the data to the server side and the form reloaded back to the ui page

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the page in "UI Builder", you need to create a "data-broker" and use it in UIB to interact with server.

Note: to make a newly created databroker work in your workspace, you need to create ACL specific to your workspace.